# Verify file copy in powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

Is there an easy way to verify all files were copied correctly when calling copy-item? I thought about using the checksum on all files, but I would imagine powershell (v2) would already have something, and I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't and here is why.  Copy-Item is a generic cmdlet that works for all namespace providers.  So the items being copied could be files, or registry settings, or IIS configuration sections, etc.  Verifying a file copy is quite a bit different than verifying a copy of registry settings.

UPDATE:
As pointed out by @Dave_S the XCOPY command's verification switch isn't the kind of verification you are looking for.

If you are copying text files you could use the PowerShell `Compare-Object` commandlet.

If you are copying binary files you could use the system `fc.exe` command with **/b** switch.

Comment: This answer is now outdated. PowerShell has had the Get-FileHash cmdlet for some time now and this is an effective and efficient method of using common methods (encryption hash) to confirm files were copied properly. This is the correct answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634939/704977

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old thread, but I thought I'd post this just in case anyone else is reading it... the /v switch *DOES NOT* verify the data!  It just makes sure that the copy is readable.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126457 for details.

Comment: This is a dead link now. Can you update the answer with detail as to what the /v switch applies too?

Answer (score 2):

Just an update, Powershell v4 includes `Get-FileHash` which can be used to verify a file was copied successfully.  If the hash is the same, the file has been copied successfully.  Link to [TechNet Library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx).

I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28601474/save-md5-hash-to-file-using-powershell/28601677) to come up with the following.

`(Get-ChildItem -file -path c:\files -Recurse).FullName | foreach {get-filehash $_ -Algorithm md5}`  Also can be piped into Export-CSV to easily visually compare the file hashes.

Comment: Downvote for misspelling "Algorithm" and adding 5 minutes figuring out what is wrong with PowerShell. :P

Comment: Coming back to comment, at least I use full param names! Instead of the shorthand `-Alg`

Comment: I found (Get-FileHash $File_Path).hash worked effectively.  No need to spell Algorithm at all :)

Answer (score 0):

My current favourite solution is xcopy in combination with a hashdeep audit. Can be packed together in a small BAT-file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use -verbose

`Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination -Recurse -Force -verbose`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do

```
$from = "D:\MyProjects\myFile.dll" 
$to = "D:\DestFolder"
Xcopy $from $to /v /f /y

# /v - verifies the to file is identical to the from file.
# /f - display from and to filenames
# /y - auto comfirm override
```