# Save md5 hash to file using powershell

Tags: powershell

When I use:

```
Get-FileHash file.ext -Algorithm MD5 |select Hash
```

the output is

```
Hash                                               
----
1231234567890ABCDEF4567890ABCDEF
```

When I use:

```
Get-FileHash file.ext -Algorithm MD5 |select Hash >file.md5
```

File content is:

```
Hash                                               
----
1231234567890ABCDEF4567890ABCDEF
```

I want in content only MD5 sum. How to implement that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use -ExpandProperty in your select.

```
Get-FileHash file.ext -Algorithm MD5 | select -ExpandProperty Hash >file.md5
```

Or like this

```
(Get-FileHash file.ext -Algorithm MD5).Hash > file.md5
```

In a loop it could look something like this (hash for "file.ext" would end up in a file called "file.ext.md5".

```
Get-ChildItem * -Include '*.ext' | foreach { (Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm MD5).Hash > "$($_.Name).md5" }
```

Comment: Your Select-Object solution is better, but I wanted to mention you can also do this with Foreach-Object.  `Get-FileHash file.ext -Algorithm MD5 | % Hash > file.md5`

Comment: When I use it in foreach loop that goes throuth list of files basenames [Get-ChildItem *.* -Include '.ext' |select BaseName]  (Get-FileHash ($list_name + '.ext') -Algorithm MD5).Hash > ($list_name + '.ext.md5') it doesn't work.

Comment: When you've got a list of filenames, use the select version, or the `% Hash` line I put above.